# Adicionar uma sequencia de imagens fixa em PHP

Tags: php, html

eu possuo este código:

```
<table class"is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
  <tr align="center" id="title">
    <td>POSIÇÃO</td>
    <td>NOME</td>
    <td>MATOU</td>
    <td>MORREU</td>
  </tr>


  <?PHP 
  $tabela = mysqli_query($connecta, "SELECT * FROM pvpm_data ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 10");
  $pos = 1;

  while($pvp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tabela)){
  echo '
  <tr align="center" id="player">

    <td>'.$pos.'º</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['kills'].'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['dies'].'</td>

  </tr>
  ';

  $pos++;
  } 
  ?>
</table>
```

É referente a um Ranking de um jogo, e eu gostaria que as 3 primeiras colocações recebessem uma imagem de uma medalha antes da numeração da posição, ex: medalha de ouro para primeira, prata para segunda e bronze para terceira. Ele está configurado para 10 colocações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem muitas maneiras.

Aqui criamos um *array* com 3 nomes:

```
  $img[1] = 'ouro.jpg';
  $img[2] = 'prata.jpg';
  $img[3] = 'bronze.jpg';
```

E um `if inline` (condicional ternário):

```
( $pos<4  ?  '<img src="'.$img[$pos].'">'  :  '' )
// ^-- se verdadeiro  ^-- retorna isto        ^-- senão retorna isto
```

Aplicando no seu código:

```
<table class"is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
  <tr align="center" id="title">
    <td>POSIÇÃO</td>
    <td>NOME</td>
    <td>MATOU</td>
    <td>MORREU</td>
  </tr>


  <?PHP 
  $tabela = mysqli_query($connecta, "SELECT * FROM pvpm_data ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 10");
  $pos = 1;
  $img[1] = 'ouro.jpg';
  $img[2] = 'prata.jpg';
  $img[3] = 'bronze.jpg';

  while($pvp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tabela)){
  echo '
  <tr align="center" id="player">
    <td>'.$pos.'º'.($pos<4?'<img src="'.$img[$pos].'">':'').'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['kills'].'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['dies'].'</td>
  </tr>
  ';

  ++$pos;
  } 
  ?>
</table>
```

A mesma lógica, mas de maneira mais fácil de ler:

```
<?PHP 
  $tabela = mysqli_query($connecta, "SELECT * FROM pvpm_data ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 10");
  $pos = 1;
  $img[1] = 'ouro.jpg';
  $img[2] = 'prata.jpg';
  $img[3] = 'bronze.jpg';

  while($pvp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tabela)){
  if ($pos < 4 ) {
     $medalha = '<img src="' . $img[$pos] . '">';
  } else {
     $medalha = '';
  }
  echo '
  <tr align="center" id="player">
    <td>'.$pos.'º'.$medalha.'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['kills'].'</td>
    <td>'.$pvp['dies'].'</td>
  </tr>
  ';

  ++$pos;
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, me ajudou muito.

Comment: Deixei uma versão alternativa para facilitar a leitura

Comment: Nossa cara, vc é 10 mesmo.